# Waiting for a process to complete in Batch file

Tags: git, powershell, batch-file

I have some bat-file

```
@echo off
call git clone ssh://username@localhost/~/repo/site C:\git\project
:end
```

How I can get callback on success cloned project and start next terminal-program?

Or I need used something another, may be PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ERRORLEVEL to see if last command failed or not

like this

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO continue
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 GOTO error

:continue
    echo do what you want here after successfully cloned
    goto exit

:error
    echo do your error handling here

:exit
```

Answer (score 1):

In poweshell you can can call the command and then check the `$lastexitcode` variable, if the command completed it will be `0` if it failed it will be `1`. Using a simple `if` you can deal with this as below:

```
call git clone ssh://username@localhost/~/repo/site C:\git\project

if ($lastexitcode) {
    Write-Host "Failed"
    #error handling code here
}
else {
    Write-Host "Completed"
}
```